# Sort words by string length

Tags: c++, fstream, words

I have a list of words in a .txt file:

```
list
of
a
thousand
words
```

I want the words sort in length order, and `ofstream` the result to a .txt file.

The output words will be like:

```
a
of
list
words
thousand
```

Any answer will be appreciated.

Comment: So you have to 1) read the words from the file, 2) store them in some kind of container, 3) measure the length of a word, 4) sort the words by length and 5) write them to another file. Which parts can you do, and which are you having trouble with?

Comment: **No**.  This is not a homework outsourcing service.

Comment: ok i know how to handle `ifstream` `ofstream` , measure it by `string.size()`, i'm not sure how to use `<vector>` to store them and sort them by order

Comment: Do you know how to use <vector> at all?

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to spoon feed you but at the same time you learn alot by looking at code. The following example uses vector as the main container and the sort function together with lambda to sort from lowest to highest.

```
std::vector<std::string> myList;

myList.push_back("why");
myList.push_back("am i");
myList.push_back("helping you with");
myList.push_back("your");
myList.push_back("homework");

std::sort(myList.begin(),myList.end(),[](const std::string& val1, const std::string& val2){
    return val1.size() < val2.size();
});

for (auto& itm : myList)
{
    std::cout << itm << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: so include `<iostream>` `<fstream>` `<vector>` `<algorithm>` and anything else i missed?